# How to make view like in the image attached?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

[image]

I want to implement the UI feature as in the image attached. The image is an screen shot form a Siemens App that is in App store. Here the bright portion can be rotated like wheel. I have gone through the link

http://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit.

but I am not able to implement the feature as in image.

Following is the link to download the Siemens app.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/siemens/id452698392?mt=8

Comment: it may be easier to use and rotate the bigger dark portion, with an alpha value almost transparent to cover the images behind it. The "shadow" effect is much easier than the bright one

Comment: But I want to orate the Image only when user drags form the bright are of the image.and I also want to spin it just like tyres where tyre stops after orating for a while depending on how much speed it has.

Comment: This question can be closed as Too Broad.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach I can think of is to use two images.  One would have the green and white detail display and one would be gray with a slight circular gradient, a lot of transparency, and a fully transparent segment.

The gray image would go on top and handle touch movement by rotating and taps according to its last stop position.

Comment: Thnx 4 ur answer.I got ur point and I can do that.The problem is how to give it a free faal rotation.When u see the siemens app u will see that touches can only on the bright area.u can rotate that area as like rotating a tyre.The bright area rotates as if u are giving motion to it.and so it rotates and stops after a while.

Comment: It seems to rotate for any moving touch, not just on the bright area.  It also responds to taps to rotate a known angle.  There is a lot of gesture handling going on.  I assume it calculates a starting rotation speed based on the touch movement and then damps it over time.